# Can my software send data to my site and read data?

Tags: c#, web, send

Can my software send information to my site and read information off my site?

Imagine that someone opens a copy of my software. The IP address of that device send to my site. So I can see if that person is a friend or not. If that person is not a friend, I will set a variable to false.
The software will then read it as false then the software will close out.

Is this possible to do? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10182935/2263683)

Comment: you can build a register and login page which will give you similar approach, ( all users to your services must be authenticated in order to access your site details)

Comment: Could you please explain what your tried and in what way it did not work for you? (You've likely already searched for something like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+send+read+data+web+site and it should be trivial to add couple links/examples to the post to make it more concrete).

Comment: You're essentially describing _[Digital Rights Management (DRM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a web service on your site then you can call the service and get an answer. You can also create a simple web page that see a white page with the result `true` or `false`. Consider using a `WCF` service so that it can expand if you needed more in the future.