# Reading data from device connected through TCP

Tags: c#, tcp

I have device (TCP/IP network controller) which is connect to my network router. To that controller is connected fingerprint scanner. What i want to do is get data of scanned finger into my c# code.

I have tried using [TCP Listner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) but nothing happened (no error or anything lese)

I have `dll` file from that product but there are lot of code in it and i am new to this so i overlooked something. Inside that `dll` i tried searching for some `EventHandler` (thought that is listening or responding when finger is placed on scanner) but there is not even one of it.

What should i look for or how should i listen to data that get's sent from that device.

Here is DLL File: [Download Link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/m4opm6n3855qyt9/n3k_controller.dll)

I know this may be too broad but please give me some hints, i am trying this for few days and still can't figure it out.

Code i tried:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                // Set the TcpListener on port 60000.
                Int32 port = 60000;

                // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
                server = new TcpListener(port);

                // Start listening for client requests.
                server.Start();

                // Buffer for reading data
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
                String data = null;

                // Enter the listening loop.
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                    // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                    data = null;

                    // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    int i;

                    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                        // Process the data sent by the client.
                        data = data.ToUpper();

                        byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                        // Send back a response.
                        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
                    }

                    // Shutdown and end connection
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Stop listening for new clients.
                server.Stop();
            }


            Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Product i am having: [LINK](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/rfid-access-controller-with-TCP-IP-door-access-control-for-2-doors-CD-sofeware-included-2/32655330330.html)

Couldn't find any documentation for it.

Comment: Please at least provide the code you have tried. What is the device brand and model? Any documentation for that specific device?

Comment: Couldn't find any documentation. Device and some code are in edited question

Comment: The device is the listener and needs to be started first. You connect using a TCPClient.  See msdn examples.  The example are for Socket class but you can use any class that inherits the socket class like TCPClient : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: @jdweng If i understand you, second example suits me `Synchronous Server Socket Example` but how do i specify what i need to catch and from where?

My device is at ip: `192.168.2.36` with port `60000` but how to know what to catch and where to specify it?

Comment: Use : IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.2.36");

Comment: `No such host is known` - this error i get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server Client send/receive simple text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182751/server-client-send-receive-simple-text)