# Re-connecting to TCP Client after timeout

Tags: c#, tcp, backgroundworker, tcpclient

I just finished programming an automated sliding door that is controlled through an app in C#. The app communicates to the motor the moves the door over TCP/IP Ethernet. I now have to make another version that can control two doors simultaneously. I immediately ran into the problem where the second motor that I attempted to communicate with would immediately disconnect if I tried to send a command at the same time. I mostly fixed this by setting up two Background Workers. Each worker loads all the necessary variables from each motor each loop and sends any commands currently queued up. Unfortunately, the motors occasionally get an overflow of commands and loose connection. When this happens, I can not re-connect.
Here is my function for sending a motor command:

```
public string[] SendMotorCommand(string motorCommand, bool timeout = true, int timeoutMS = 2000)
    {
        string[] messagesReceived = null;
        if (connected)
        {
            try
            {
                //example from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182751/server-client-send-receive-simple-text

                //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
                NetworkStream nwStream = Client.GetStream();
                if (timeout)
                    nwStream.ReadTimeout = timeoutMS;
                else
                    nwStream.ReadTimeout = -1;
                byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(motorCommand + "\r");
                nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
                /*if (motorCommand.Contains("PR"))
                {*/
                    //---read back the text---

                    byte[] data = new byte[Client.ReceiveBufferSize];

                    int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                    string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead).Trim();

                    messagesReceived = str.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                //}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to send or receive command " + motorCommand + " at IP " + ip);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                Client.Close();
                Client = new TcpClient();
                Client.Connect(ip, 503);

            }
        }
        return (messagesReceived);
    }
```

As you can see, if the motor fails to communicate, I close the current client and create it again, however, I can never reconnect after the initial communication failure. The only way I can get them to work again is by re-starting the app. The fact that nothing has changed with the Ethernet connection makes me think that I should be able to reliably re-establish the connection if it fails.

There are probably about 20 of these commands that run in a loop, but there is a possibility for many to be queued up, especially if commands keep timing out. Is it possible that a bunch of commands are getting queued up and these are still being processed by the Ethernet interface? As a temporary fix, I set up my app to restart itself if a command fails, when this happens, it usually restarts a few times before staying on again. This makes me think that there are still some things being processed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was an issue with my command queue.

This is how my commands were being sent:

```
string[] currentCommands = commands.ToArray();
                commands.Clear();

                foreach (string command in currentCommands)
                {
                    SendMotorCommand(command);
                }
```

It looks like randomly, this character was being sent as a command () Not sure how to display it but it looks like a small L that is higher up. This seemed to crash the communication. Not sure how it is getting in there as I never add this character to the queue, but I suspect it has something to do with converting the commands to an array. It's possible this gets interrupted if a command is added while the loop is running. I am now doing a check in the "SendMotorCommand" funtion to skip the command if that is what is being sent. This solves the problem, but would like to know why this is happening if anyone has ideas.